# Show selective column data from multiple SPS lists

Tags: list, sharepoint-server

How can I show selective column data from multiple lists within a webpart on the homepage.Such that it shows the aggregate information for specific column data from multiple lists.

Environment: SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 1):

If you need to show data from multiple list then there is no predefined direct WebPart available. But You can make use of Content Search WebPart in tricky way in order to achieve this functionality.

Its little bit tricky but it will definitely work because i already gone through this requirement.

This can be achieved using SharePoint Search Service Application. You can bind the search result from Search Service Application directly into Content Search WebPart.

Here is the best ever explanation for your problem. Lets have a look to this thread.

[How to get data from multiple table or list in SharePoint 2013?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112085/how-to-get-data-from-multiple-table-or-list-in-sharepoint-2013)

Let me know whether this solves your requirment or need some more.

Thanks

Comment: Aakash, Thanks for responding.
I`ve gone through the article.

Comment: Aakash, my understnading this would show data from a specific column from multiple lists. Which is good, but my requirement is to have data from multiple columns from multiple lists in one webpart (imagine if u r showing a list based dashboard)

Comment: Ok. Let me check and verify at my end

Comment: any update did you got a chance to check?

Comment: The link i provided worked for me, i tried the same procedure given there.