# Can't retrieve all Items from all lists that reside on a single subsite

Tags: rest, csom, sharepoint-rest-api, ajax, jquery-ajax

SP Community, I am absolutely stumped and desperate for help. I have been up and down StackExchange trying to get 3 separate attempts to -
1. query all of the lists within a subsite and to then -
2. filter the query based on criteria in the title.

I need to retrieve all items within each list in a subsite. Once I do that, I need to filter by list title so that only information from lists containing "RDTEN" or "procurement" in their title get parsed.
With the end result, I need to build a graph for the aggregated information.

Please see attempts below, these are my starting points, none of which are currently working:

**AJAX**
    
    
    Test with Multiple Lists - Ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var siteUrl = 'https://site/subsite';

// Load the required SharePoint libraries.
$(document).ready(function () {

    // The js files are in a URL in the form:
    // web_url/_layouts/15/resource_file
    var scriptbase =  siteUrl  + "/_layouts/15/";

    // Load the js files and continue to
    // the execOperation function.
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",
    function () {
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", execOperation);
        }
    );
});

// Function to execute basic operations.
function execOperation() {

    // Continue your program flow here.
    retrieveWebSiteProperties(siteUrl);

}

function retrieveWebSiteProperties(siteUrl) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    this.oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    this.collList = oWebsite.get_lists();
    this.listInfoCollection = clientContext.load(collList);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listInfo = '';
    var listEnumerator = this.collList.getEnumerator();
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
        listInfo += 'Title: ' + oList.get_title() + ' Created: ' + 
oList.get_created().toString() + '\n';
    }
    $("#chartArea").html(listInfo);

}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>

<body>
<div id="chartArea"></div>
</body>
```

**CSOM**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var context;
var web;
var collList;
$(document).ready(function () {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getLists);
});

function getLists() {
    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = context.get_web();
    collList = web.get_lists();
    context.load(collList);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFailure);
}
function onRequestSuccess() {
    var listInfo = '';
    var listEnumerator = collList.getEnumerator();
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
        if(oList.get_title().indexOf("pro") !== -1){ //if title contains "pro"
            listInfo += '<div>Title: ' + oList.get_title() + ' Created: ' + 
oList.get_created().toString() + '</div>';
        }
    }

    $("#chartArea").html(listInfo);
}
function onRequestFailure(sender, args) {
    $("#chartArea").html('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + 
args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>

<body>
<div id="chartArea"></div>
</body>
```

**REST**

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Test with Multiple Lists - Rest</title>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Set the REST endpoint to use. 
// This one includes a filter to only return lists whose title includes "Site"
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists? 
$filter=substringof('Site', 
Title)";

// Create the AJAX request using jQuery. 
var request = jQuery.ajax({ url: url, headers: { "Accept": 
"Application/json;odata=nometadata" } });

   // Use a .then() callback to do something with data after its returned by the server
 request.then(
     function (d) {
      // For each result in the set of returned data
      d.value.forEach(
          function (i) {
              // Print the Title of the list to the console
              console.log(i.Title);
          });
  });

 </script>

<body>
<div id="chartArea"></div>
</body>
```

**Note**: My original question was put on hold for being unclear, I wrote a new question in hopes to provide additional clarity.

Comment: I refactored my code a bit... Might be easier to read now? Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a script here that'll do most of what you're looking for. Currently it doesn't create a graph or any fancy stuff but it does collect the info you're looking for. Be careful that your internal column name actually is `Title` or you'll have to change it in the for loops in `getSPListData_SecondQuery_Success`.

The only things you'll really need to change is the variables `siteUrl`, and potentially `expr`. The data from each list is sent to the `manageData` function under `allData` whereas the items that meet your criteria will be sent to `oListData`.

`siteUrl` must be the absolute url of the site, without including the page. For example: http://mySites/sample/infrastructure rather than http://mySites/sample/infrastructure/home.aspx.

`expr` is a regex expression. In this case it's saying *find any instance of "RDTEN" or "procurement", case insensitive*. If you need help with regex expressions, there's lots of guides you can find with a quick google search. In JS they are notated by `/<pattern>/<flags>`.

In `manageData` you can use `console.log(allData)` or `console.log(oListData)` to see what's in the respective items.

The general flow has been split into functions as I find it easier to read that way... Here's an outline:

> Load JavaScript libraries with an anonymous function.
>
> Wait for `SP.js` to load for `SP.ClientContext` to be loaded, then call `getSPListData`
>
> **getSPListData** :: Prepare and execute the first query to gather all the lists.
>
> > If successful, send current context to `getSPListData_SecondQuery` and prepare second query
> >
> > If failed, log the issue through `getSPListData_LogError`.
>
> **getSPListData_SecondQuery** :: Prepare and execute second query to gather all items in lists.
>
> > If successful, send current context to `getSPListData_SecondQuery_Success` to process the list items.
> >
> > If failed, log the issue through `getSPListData_LogError`.
>
> **getSPListData_SecondQuery_Success** :: Process items by looking at the title of every list item. If matches, push into a list.... Once complete, push the valid list data (`oListData`) and all item (`result`, or `allData` in the next function) to `manageData`.
>
> **manageData** :: Used to manipulate the list items in the array. Can use `console.log(oListItems)` or `console.log(allData)` to view whats in the respective arrays in the console. Currently puts the first 5 into a list wherever your Code Editor is on the page.

This isn't the most efficient evaluation as it does the two queries which can take time, and then at the end it has a rather large run-time complexity from the nested for loops. If you've got a lot of lists or items, you may need to optimize some of it.

Just paste and edit this into a Script Editor on whatever page you want. Right now it creates a div to send the data to in the form of...

```
Title = itemTitle
Library = relativeUrl
Blank Line
```

Heres the script:

```
Files: <br/><div id="listItemData"></div><br/>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Loads libraries from CDNs... 
javascript: ( function() {
    function l( u, i ) {
        var d = document;
        if ( !d.getElementById( i ) ) {
            var s = d.createElement( 'script' );
            s.src = u;
            s.id = i;
            s.async = true;
            d.body.appendChild( s );
        }
    }
    // l( url, idForElem )
    l( '//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js', 'msAjax' )
    l( '//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js', 'jQuery' )
} )();

// Wait for SP.js to finish loading before we run the queries.
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded( getSPListData, 'SP.js' );

function getSPListData() {
    // Set up the first query
    this.result = [];
    this.siteUrl = 'http(s)://mySite/sample/subSite'; // Change this to your subsite in question.
    this.ctx = new SP.ClientContext( siteUrl )
    this.lists = ctx.get_web().get_lists();
    this.expr = /(RDTEN)|(procurement)/i // This is what you're searching for in the Title field, "i" for case insensitive search.
    this.ctx.load( this.lists, "Include(Id,Title)" );

    ctx.executeQueryAsync( 
      this.getSPListData_SecondQuery.bind(this), 
      this.getSPListData_LogError.bind(this) 
    );

}

function getSPListData_SecondQuery(sender, args){
   lists.get_data().forEach( function( list ) {
      // Set up the second query and push its results into the "Result" array
      var items = list.getItems( SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery() );
      ctx.load( items );
      // This entry is the list's base data
      var listEntry = {
           id: list.get_id().toString(),
           title: list.get_title()
      }
      // Push the data into result, items will have all items in each list.
      result.push( {
           list: listEntry,
           items: items
      } );
   } );
   ctx.executeQueryAsync(
      this.getSPListData_SecondQuery_Success.bind(this),
      this.getSPListData_LogError.bind(this)
   );
}

function getSPListData_SecondQuery_Success(sender, args){
   //transform listitem properties. This is where the "items" section of "Result" is filled out.
   result.forEach( function( item ) {
       item.items = item.items.get_data().map( function( listItem ) {
          return listItem.get_fieldValues();
       } );
   } );

   // Filter each by the ReGex expression earlier on the Title field.
   var oListData = [];
   var itemTitle;
   for ( listNum = 0, listTot = result.length; listNum < listTot; listNum++ ) {
       for ( itemNum = 0, itemTot = result[ listNum ].items.length; itemNum < itemTot; itemNum++ ) {
          itemTitle = result[ listNum ].items[ itemNum ].Title
          if ( itemTitle && itemTitle.match( expr ) ) {
               // put data into a list
               oListData.push( result[ listNum ].items[ itemNum ] )
          }
       }
   }
   // Here's where you can make the data visible. in the manageData function.
   manageData( oListData, result );
}

// incase an error comes up in the execution of the queries
function getSPListData_LogError( sender, args ) {
    console.log( args.get_message() ); 
}

function manageData( oListData, allData ) {
    // Do stuff with list items here...
    var oListDataField = document.getElementById( "listItemData" );
    var stringBuilding = '';

    for(i=0, itemMax = Math.min(5, oListData.length); i < itemMax; i++){
        stringBuilding += " Title = " + oListData[i].Title + "<br/>"
        stringBuilding += " Library = " + oListData[i].FileDirRef + "<br/><br/>"
    }
    oListDataField.innerHTML = stringBuilding

    // For seeing the relative data:
    console.log(allData)
    console.log(oListData)
}

</script>
```

Comment: thanks so much for this KGlasier, testing it out this morning

Comment: okay @Torybee and if the site you want the list items from is the same as the site you want to display it, you should be able to replace `this.ctx = new SP.ClientContext(site);` for `this.ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();`... That should make it useable on any site without alteration if you want the same title search

Comment: great to know, this is working for me! A little slow like you said but I can work on that. I really appreciate your help, thanks so much

Comment: @Torybee I got the skeleton of this code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48093356/get-all-lists-and-list-items-in-a-sharepoint-site-with-jsom) but it links to a possible method to do all this in a *single request* which you may want to look into for speed ([Request Batching - CSOM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff798420(v=pandp.10))). Also using a better query would improve response time as you may be able to search for your RegEx items in the query itself, removing that double for loop. And an upvote is always appreciated ;)

Comment: I'll definitely keep that in mind, I tried to upvote you but my account is too young apparently haha I have less than 15 reputation :(

Comment: No worries! Good luck on optimizing @Torybee

Comment: I haven't had any success optimizing thus far :( I tried to load only items for lists that match the regex in title by moving the condition itemTitle.match(expr) before the result.push({list: listEntry, items: items});. That didn't work for me, also tried search api. Are you still available for help with this?

Comment: @Torybee Sorry but I don't think I'll be much help. But how long is it taking to load? How many items and how many libraries is it pulling from? How many are typically being returned?

Comment: It takes 20 seconds to load, loading 36 lists and ~6,000 items total. All are being returned, the filter portion didn't take. Which is fine, I just can't seem to separate the two now and have it functioning as it originally did.

Comment: @Torybee If you've got access to SPD, you could create a workflow to attach to each library. Have it search the fields you want for the values you want, and use the action that's something like "Create item in Library". This would create a duplicate of the current document and put it in the library you want. Then it's just as simple as putting the WebPart for that new library in your page. You'll have to run it on all your documents that currently exist, but that should be doable with a powershell script? Then you can just have the workflow run "On item creation" or "Edit"...

Comment: so the only problem with that is, the 6,000 items we currently have will continue to grow. The last iteration of this had over 20K items total and we ran into a lot of issues with surpassing the list item threshold

Comment: @Torybee Okay, try looking at [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/112088/77489) and run a CQWP on the page. The query you could put in the advanced section is something like `path:<to your web of interest>  (IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem") Title:Procurement Title:RDTEN` but that'll pull from subsites too. To prevent subsites you'd have to list in the path to each list like this `(Path:<list1> OR Path:<list2> OR ... ) ...`  But that might not be an option either. Worth a shot!