# JQuery Preloader on SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, jquery, preloader

I am having trouble getting a simple jQuery preloader to work. I've tried a couple different methods, I've also moved the function around in the code. Can anyone shed some light on why this isn't working and what the solution would be?

**Updated to include the entirety of my code:**

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded( getSPListData, 'SP.js' );

$(window).load(function() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
});

function getSPListData() {
    this.result = [];
    this.siteUrl = 
'https://site/subsite/'; 
    this.ctx = new SP.ClientContext( siteUrl )
    this.lists = ctx.get_web().get_lists();
    this.expr = /(RDTEN)|(procurement)/i 
    this.ctx.load( this.lists, "Include(Id,Title)" );

    ctx.executeQueryAsync( 
      this.getSPListData_SecondQuery.bind(this), 
      this.getSPListData_LogError.bind(this) 
    );

}

function getSPListData_SecondQuery(sender, args){
   lists.get_data().forEach( function( list ) {
      // Set up the second query and push its results into the "Result" array
      var items = list.getItems( SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery() );
      ctx.load( items );
      // This entry is the list's base data
      var listEntry = {
           id: list.get_id().toString(),
           title: list.get_title()
      }
      // Push the data into result, items will have all items in each list.
      result.push( {
           list: listEntry,
           items: items
      } );
   } );
   ctx.executeQueryAsync(
      this.getSPListData_SecondQuery_Success.bind(this),
      this.getSPListData_LogError.bind(this)
   );
}

function getSPListData_SecondQuery_Success(sender, args){
   //transform listitem properties.
   result.forEach( function( item ) {
       item.items = item.items.get_data().map( function( listItem ) {
          return listItem.get_fieldValues();
       } );
   } );


*_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('hideLoader');
function hideLoader() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut(1500);
}*

   // Filter each by the ReGex expression earlier on the Title field.
   var oListData = [];
   var itemTitle;
   for ( listNum = 0, listTot = result.length; listNum < listTot; listNum++ ) 
{
       for ( itemNum = 0, itemTot = result[ listNum ].items.length; itemNum < 
itemTot; itemNum++ ) {
          itemTitle = result[ listNum ].items[ itemNum ].Title
          if ( itemTitle && itemTitle.match( expr ) ) {
               // put data into a list
               oListData.push( result[ listNum ].items[ itemNum ] )
          }
       }
   }


   // Here's where you can make the data visible. in the manageData function.
   manageData( oListData, result );
}

// incase an error comes up in the execution of the queries
function getSPListData_LogError( sender, args ) {
    console.log( args.get_message() ); 
}

function manageData( oListData, allData ) {
    // Do stuff with list items here...
    var oListDataField = document.getElementById( "listItemData" );
    var stringBuilding = '';

    for(i=0, itemMax = Math.min(5, oListData.length); i < itemMax; i++){
        stringBuilding += " Title = " + oListData[i].Title + "<br/>"
        stringBuilding += " Library = " + oListData[i].FileDirRef + "<br/><br/>"
    }
    oListDataField.innerHTML = stringBuilding

    // For seeing the relative data:
     console.log(allData)
     console.log(oListData)

}
```

This is the CSS/HTML associated with the jQuery

```
<style type="text/css">
.loader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: fuchsia;
    opacity: .8;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
Files:<div id="listItemData"></div>
<div class="loader"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: What’s the error saying in the developer console (F12 screen)?

Comment: As of now, there is no console error. I just get a blank page and the list data no longer loads either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting `$(".loader").fadeOut("slow");` into `$(window).load` will lead to it being called immediatelly when the page finishes loading, thereby directly hiding the loader.

But that is typically much earlier than when your CSOM query is ready.

What you actually want to do is to hide that loader **after** your CSOM query/queries finish. I would do the following:

Pack the hiding into a function:

```
function hideLoader() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
}
```

Then call that function both in `getSPListData_SecondQuery` (or if you also fire off any more queries there, put it in the last function being called asynchronously) and `getSPListData_LogError` functions, i.e. only after the queries finished or failed.

Comment: Figured it out, added
 _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('hideLoader');
function hideLoader() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut(45000);
}
to the very bottom of my code and that worked. Thanks for the help @KGlasier and Anon

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `loader` is an id, not a class. Try changing your scripts accordingly in the CSS and JavaScript.

### — previous answer —

I think the duration for `$().fadeOut("slow");` is about 0.6 seconds. Using `$(window).load();` can be tricky with SharePoint, as the body of it loads differently than the actual window. Essentially, your "fadeOut" has already been executed by the time the body actually loads.

A solution for this is to use the `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("functionHandle");` which will execute the script you're looking for *after* the body has loaded.

Also rather than putting in `slow` for the argument, try puting in a time (in milliseconds) for greater control. Something like this may work, instead of your `$(window).load(...)`

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('hideLoader');
function hideLoader() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut(1500);
}
```

If I remember correctly, your last question said the script made it [load in ~20 seconds](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/255195/cant-retrieve-all-items-from-all-lists-that-reside-on-a-single-subsite/255200#comment273948_255200). So you might want to make the delay a similar time. But this should at least make it work, visibly.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88774/discussion-on-answer-by-kglasier-jquery-preloader-on-sharepoint-2013).